# How to detect whether user didEnterBackground because of phone call or click on home button?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

We have a multiplayer game and sometimes user quit the game so we would like to know how did user quit the game. Can we use `didEnterBackground` for that?

We would like to know whether user quit the game by clicking exit button, or by incoming call, or by home button to exit.

Comment: Maybe the best answer is this question: Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press home button your application is sent to background and `applicationDidEnterBackground` will get call first and if it is by call, sms then `applicationWillResignActive` will get call first.

This is not perfect answer of your question but this might help you in some.

Answer (score 0):

in the appDelegate.m File u have this function:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
```

write the code you want in it. (saving data or anything)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the user interface guidelines forbid quitting an app programmatically and based on what I have read, apps the provide an exit button will be rejected.

If by 'quit the game' you mean something along the lines of 'terminated gameplay', then that should not be a problem.

Also note that pressing the home button does not exit the app. It simply sends it to the background. There does not appear to be any facility to detect why the app left the foreground, which probably means that Apple wants your app to handle all such cases in the same way: by saving state and being prepared to restart where execution left off. Note that an application in the background can be terminated at any time, hence the need to save state.

The answer to your question therefore would seem to be: don't do that.